# Автор и архитектор — однородные или неоднородные приложения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, приложение

**Автор собора, архитектор Антонио Гауди заслуживает того, чтобы быть причисленным к лику святых.**

Разве *автор* и *архитектор* — однородные приложения?

Answer (score 5):

Автор собора - не корректное сочетание. Сохраняя в целом, лучше дополнить: Автор **проекта** собора архитектор Антонио Гауди. В этом случае запятой может и не быть, на мой взгляд.

Comment: По поводу того, что "автор проекта собора" звучит лучше и логичнее, чем "автор собора", согласен, но хотел бы заметить, что 4 существительных подряд — это моветон для людей, которые пишут статьи, делают переводы и пр., насколько я знаю. По крайней мере, их учат избегать таких словосочетаний.

Answer (score 3):

"Автор собора архитектор Антонио Гауди заслуживает того, чтобы быть причисленным к лику святых"(без запятой).

Корректное выражение - автор проекта собора, но в разговорной и публицистической речи допускается "автор собора". например: "Теперь самое интересное. Кто же автор собора? Когда построен? Ответ – неизвестно, неизвестно".

В приведенном примере приложения лучше считать неоднородными вследствие их малой распространенности и легко узнаваемого статуса подобных сочетаний, например: "Мой друг писатель Иванов написал статью на эту тему".

Это похоже на неоднородные приложения определенных тематических групп:   главный конструктор проектного института инженер NN; первый заместитель министра обороны РФ генерал армии NN;генеральный директор производственного объединения кандидат технических наук NN.

Answer (score 1):

Можно трактовать и как однордные. Тут от стилистики зависит. 
Без запятой фраза зрительно плохо воспринимается.